# react-snap, Error: no such file or directory index.html in dist

Tags: vue.js, laravel-mix, react-snap

there is no index.html in my dist folder and I don’t understand when and how it should be created

laravel vue webpack.mix

```
root@e6cacbaaed15:/var/www/html# npm run postbuild

> postbuild
> react-snap

node:events:492
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/var/www/html/dist/index.html'
Emitted 'error' event on ReadStream instance at:
    at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:151:8)
    at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:116:3)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
  errno: -2,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'open',
  path: '/var/www/html/dist/index.html'
}

Node.js v18.17.1
```

I need to setup prerender in my project, by i had a more troubles with it